# Create a UserControl derived from an abstract base class, and give it an X:Name?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, abstract

I have a non-abstract user control derived from an abstract base class and therefore I have to use the abstract base class in the XAML code as the base. This is valid c# code in terms of type inheritance and class instantiability. It seems that the designer has problems with it:

> MC3054: The type "MyAbstractClass" cannot have a Name attribute. Value types and types without default constructor can be used as items within a ResourceDictionary

I have the following type hierarchy:

```
public interface IMyInterface { void Init(); }

public abstract class MyAbstractClass: UserControl, IMyInterface
{ public abstract void Init(); }

public MyDerivedClass: MyAbtractClass
{ public void Init() {} }
```

and the following xaml section

```
< local:MyAbstractClass x:Name="myObject" x:Class="MyDerivedClass"
                       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace" >
...
```

When I compile it I get the  MC3054 error from title.

Changing the abstract class into non abstract makes it compilable and executable.

Why isn't it possible to use an abstract base class in xaml in this way, **when the derived class is not abstract**?

My abstract and derived classes have default constructors explicitly defined.

Comment: You can't create an instance of abstract class, that's the main point here, have a look at [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-and-custom-classes-for-wpf) for details

Comment: You code will not compile, please correct it

Comment: It seems that my comment was deleted:

Please read the sample carefully.
I do not create instances of abstract classes.
I have a user control based on an abstract class and therefore I have to use the abstract base class in the XAML code as the base.

This is valid c# code in terms of type inheritance and class instantiability.
It seems that the designer has problems with it.